# MultiLine textbox in html for php script

Tags: php, html, textbox, multiline

all,

I wanted to create a multiline textbox but all the info i googled on it says that i can adjust the length but no the height

How would i create a text box field that i could have a user type comments into for a php script?

this is what I'm currently using

```
<INPUT TYPE = "TEXT" >
```

Bonus question:

how do i disable enter in the text box ( like if you hit "this is a test+ enter" it submits the page i want the user to have to click on the submit button at the bottom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean a [textarea](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_textarea.asp)? Or an [editable div](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/HTML/UsingthecontentEditableProperty.htm)?

Comment: text area seems the correct one. Can i access that text from a php script?

Comment: @Crash893 - yes you can, give it a name attribute, and get the value from $_GET or $_POST in PHP. See http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php